# Magento Paypal not displaying transaction details

Tags: magento, paypal

Magento 1.8

Starting from last week orders that were received via Paypal didnt appear as paid status at the backend and paypal transaction details were missing.

What could cause that? We are using default paypal bundled with Magento.

#### Default display fields:

- Payer ID:
- Payer Email:
- Payer Status:
- Payer Address Status:
- Merchant Protection Eligibility:
- Last Transaction ID:
- Order was placed using MYR

#### Current display field

[image: Empty paypal transaction details]